# How to stack two lines of subscripts?

Tags: equations, subscripts

How do I type two lines of subscript as shown below?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! With `substack`, for example `\[ 
\sum_{\substack{1\le\le n\\
                1<j<k}}
\]`

Answer (score 2):

With use of the `substack`.

[image]

With using the `amsmath` package, you can simply define math operator for `dist` (it should be in upright letters):

```
\documentclass[varwidth, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareMathOperator{\dist}{dist}

\begin{document}
\[
C=\sum_{\substack{1\leq i\leq n\\ 1 <j <k}}\dist(d_i,c_j)
\]
or

\[
C=\sum\nolimits_{\substack{1\leq i\leq n\\ 1 <j <k}}\dist(d_i,c_j)
\]
\end{document}
```